# change color input field on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Bootstrap 4 and want to change background color of an input field by clicking button.

here is my code:

```
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Dein Ersparniss / Jahr</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtres" readonly>
            </div>
        </div>
```

here is button:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Berechnen" onClick="sumValues()">
```

Can someone help me with jQuery?

Comment: What's your jQuery code so far? To what element do you want to change the background color?

Answer (score 1):

`.css('background-color','blue')` use this method on your input you want to change color. You access the the input by name like this `$('input[name="txtres"]')`

```js
function sumValues(){
  $('input[name="txtres"]').css('background-color','blue')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
            <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Dein Ersparniss / Jahr</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtres" readonly>
            </div>
        </div>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Berechnen" onclick="sumValues()">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `.click` event to your button and then change the color of your input field using `.css()`:

```js
$('.color-btn').click(function() {
  $('.input-color').css({color: 'red', 'background-color': 'black'});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Dein Ersparniss / Jahr</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input value="Some text" class="input-color" type="text" class="form-control" name="txtres" readonly />
  </div>
</div>

<input type="button" class="color-btn btn btn-danger" value="Berechnen" />
```

Here I have given your button the class `color-btn` so it can be targeted using jquery easily, and have also given your text box the class `input-color`. Thus, any input element with the class `input-color` will be able to change color when your button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Use `css()` for changing bgcolor on click of button

```js
function sumValues(e){
$('input[name=txtres]').css('backgroundColor','red')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Dein Ersparniss / Jahr</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtres" readonly>
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Berechnen" onClick="sumValues()">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what I would do

```js
$('btn-danger').css("background-color", "blue");

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn-danger').on( "click", function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').css("background-color", "blue");
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Dein Ersparniss / Jahr</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtres" readonly>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Berechnen" onClick="sumValues()">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

over here you'rs listening to a click even on the button and change the background color of the text input after click

check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ukdx3f05/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a `css class` with desired `background-color` and then add that `class` to input when `button` is clicked. It's just another way you can do this:

```js
sumValues = function(){
  $('input[name="txtres"]').addClass( "colored-background" );
}
```

```css
.colored-background {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Dein Ersparniss / Jahr</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtres" readonly>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Berechnen" onClick="sumValues()">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```